# Dynamically add or remove height and overflow-Y scroll property of a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I have two sections [divs] on a page which is based on bootstrap. The left section contains a bootstrap panel which initially is resized to occupy the full page and then on clicking a glyph on the panel header, right section slides in sharing the page with the left panel. The contents of the right section are also panels whose contents are dynamic[table and dynamic rows]. The left panel is coded to always occupy window height. What I want is the right side div also to always occupy the window height and for overflow let a scroll appear for the right hand section. If I hard code the height of the right hand section and then give overflow-y: scroll, then it works. But I want to provide both using javascript and the height to be window width. Please help.

```
    <body style = "height: 100%; overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="navigationbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TRAMM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="menu">
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>                            
                    <li><a href="">Page1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page4</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main-wrapper" class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top: 1%">
                <div class="panel-heading" id="JnName">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            NAME : Somename
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right;">
                            <span class="toggle-button bs-tooltip" id="ShowButton" style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Click to toggle sidebar">
                                <span id="glyphbutton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                      
                <div class="panel-body" id="SVGPanel">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="col-sm-6 sidebar">
            <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top: 1%;" id="JunctionParam">
                <div class="panel-heading" id="JunctionParameters">Junction Parameters</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                        Please fill the content which is more than the window height here...
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And I have tried this. But it does not seem to be working

```
    function autoAdjust()
    {
        var $sidebarwrapperscroller;
        $sidebarwrapperscroller = document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper');
        $sidebarwrapperscroller.style.height = $(window).height();
        alert("setheight");
        $sidebarwrapperscroller.style.overflowY = "scroll";
    }
```

But without any javascript, if I set

```
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="col-sm-6 sidebar" style="height: 700px; overflow-y:scroll;">
```

Then its working. But I want the height to be set to window height dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you you need to add overflow-y:scroll and height:auto to sidebar-wrapper ?
Maybe with jquery?

```
$("#sidebar-wrapper").click(function() {
    if ( $("#sidebar-wrapper").css('display') == 'visible' ){
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").css({"height":"auto", "overflow-y":"scroll"}); 
    }else{
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").css({"height":"", "overflow-y":""});
    }
});
```

Replace sidebar-wrapper id with your glyph id in .click function

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/et08c6ab/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but is it sufficient that it be added just once? As I said the 'sidebar-wrapper' slides in only at the click on a glyph.  And will it work on window resize too?

Comment: Well you need height to be auto set depend on browser height? So height:auto will do this and overflow-y:scroll will do the slide functionality. 
So you can set to do this on a glyph click do add css and when panel is closed to remove css?
I edited code in my answer so try it...

Comment: Thanks, I have not tried this, but in my original post,

         $sidebarwrapperscroller.style.height = $(window).height()+"px";

does the trick... ;) 

But height: auto just means the size of the div depends on the content inside it right? So wouldnt it simply increase irrespective of the window size?

Comment: I just tested your suggestion and its just adding an overall scroll and not for the right div alone. Right side div automatically increases or decreases height according to content. Scroll doesnt appear.

Comment: Do you have a link of a website so I can check it?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tattushenoi/et08c6ab/) is a fiddle link that I have created... In the javascript function I have commented and kept my code as well. 

I have not done the whole thing - the sliding in of the right hand side and all that - as the requirement was a scroll on the right hand side.

P.S: You might need to stretch the page portion a bit to the left to see left and right sides side by side. Otherwise it appears top down.

Comment: Yep, thanks for another solution. I needed to expand the left div to full screen on click of that glyph in addition to the right div sliding out. But I have done that.

Comment: No problem. Do you want to add that to code ?
Is my solution ok? Is that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.